# Convert a string into list of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, magento, explode, fgetcsv

How do I convert a REQUEST string into arrays in a list like the following?

```
$_REQUEST["InventoryData"] == sku=qty&234444=11&ShirtBig=111&ShirtSmall=101&empty=0

Array ( [0] => sku [1] => qty ) 
Array ( [0] => 234444 [1] => 11 ) 
Array ( [0] => ShirtBig [1] => 111 ) 
Array ( [0] => ShirtSmall [1] => 101 ) 
Array ( [0] => empty [1] => 0 )
```

This is a modification of "MASS UPDATE STOCK LEVELS IN MAGENTO – FAST" script for updating using a client side submission of data.

Comment: Please format your code properly: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array();
parse_str($_REQUEST['InventoryData'], $data);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $result[] = array($key, $value);
}
```

Comment: `parse_str`... what a great name for a function. :D

Comment: Yep.  I was looking for a name like `http_parse_query` to go along with the complementary function `http_build_query`.  PHP has so much stuff already built in; the trouble is freaking *finding* it sometimes.  :)

Comment: This works except it gives me an array of arrays. I just need a list of arrays. If I print_r(array($key, $value)); I get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the explode function to split strings into arrays by a certain character:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

However you may need to do some string manipulation to get that string into the structure you posted.