# string to array with desired keys

Tags: php, arrays, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a string into list of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754645/convert-a-string-into-list-of-arrays)

I have a string code=AA&price=10&user_id=5.initially i exploded first with & and then by =  but i getting.

```
array(
      [0] =>code
      [0] =>AA
      [0] =>price
      [0] =>10
      [0] =>user_id
      [0] =>5

 )
```

My aim is to show

```
array(
       [code]     => AA
       [price]    => 10
       [user_id]  => 5

)
```

Comment: Multiple keys with the same value? Are you sure? Ever heard of [`parse_str()`](http://www.php.net/parse_str)?

Answer (score 5):

```
parse_str($str, $values);
var_dump($values);
```

You are parsing a URL encoded format, use the already existing [`parse_str`](http://php.net/parse_str) to parse it.

Answer (score 4):

```
$string = 'code=AA&price=10&user_id=5';
$params = array();
parse_str($string, $params);
print_r($params);
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

> parse_str — Parses the string into variables

```
parse_str('code=AA&price=10&user_id=5', $outputArray);
```

Comment: You can have a +1 from me if you add a `$` symbol to `outputArray` :)

Comment: @Dale - hahaha handing out "pity +1's"

Comment: @LastCoder No I like this answer it's nice and short!